# Can any one suggest what ".>" do in julia lang

Tags: julia

Can any one suggest what .> will do in below code. I have tried to run without . and it failed

`array6[:, 1] .> 12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array6[:, 1] .> 12
```

is the same as

```
broadcast(>, array6[:, 1], 12)
```

You can check the details what `broadcast` does in its docstring.

You can also have a look at https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#Array-and-Vectorized-Operators-and-Functions-1 and https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1 sections (including the links therein) in the Julia manual, which explain how and why such operations work.

Let me just give a short comment. You try to compare using `>` a vector (one column of a matrix `array6`) and a scalar (`12`). Such an operation is not well defined in mathematics by default, so Julia does not allow it either.

What broadcasting does in this case is that it *spreads* the object with a lower dimensionality (a scalar, which has dimension `0`, which you can check by writing `ndims(12)`) to the dimension of the object with a higher dimensionality (a vector in this case, which has dimension `1`, which you can check by writing `ndims(array6[:, 1])`). Spreading is performed by just repeating the value `12` as many times as needed in the target dimension to make the sizes of both objects match (technically what should match after spreading is what is returned by `axes` function). Then if you have two objects of the same size a function `>` is applied to each matching elements of both objects.